# When i try to edit one field, the other one is set to NULL in Firestore Database Android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

After the user login, his account details are displaying in the application, but they have the possibility to edit these fields. They can change the username, display name, and phone number. I tried to change the display name( for updating username is another method), but when I do this, the phone number is set to null and vice versa. Is something wrong with my code? I am a beginner at Firestore Database.

```
private FirebaseFirestore dbFirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private DocumentReference userRef;
userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

```
public void updateUserAccountSettings(String displayName, String phoneNumber) {

        Log.d(TAG, "updateUserAccountSettings: updating user account settings.");


        userRef = db.collection("Users")
                .document(userID);

        userRef.update("display_name", displayName
        ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: update is succesful");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: update failed ");
                }

            }
        });

        userRef.update("phone_number", phoneNumber
        ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: update is succesful");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: update failed ");
                }

            }
        });
```

```
/**
         * change the rest of the settings that do not require uniqueness
         */
        if(!mUser.getDisplay_name().equals(displayName)){
            //update displayname
            mFirebaseMethods.updateUserAccountSettings(displayName, null);
        }
        if(mUser.getPhone_number().equals(phoneNumber)){
            //update phoneNumber
            mFirebaseMethods.updateUserAccountSettings(null, phoneNumber);
        }
```

this is where I called the method and I want to tell that because when I verify for display_name if it is changed, I set the phone number to null and vice versa, but before this worked fine with Real-time Database.

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling the method updateUserAccountSettings, both  userRef.update("display_name", displayName ...)
and userRef.update("phone_number", phoneNumber ...) is being run. In your if condition, one of the value is null. As both those functions run regardless, you’ll always have one value that is going to be null. One approach would be to put an If Else condition to check if the value is null,

```
 if(displayName != null){
 userRef.update("display_name", displayName
        ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: update is succesful");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: update failed ");
                }

            }
        });
 }
 else{

        userRef.update("phone_number", phoneNumber
        ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: update is succesful");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: update failed ");
                }

            }
        });
}
```

Second approach would be to have separate functions to update the values, and call those respective function from your if condition

```
if(!mUser.getDisplay_name().equals(displayName)){
            //update displayname
            mFirebaseMethods.updateUserDisplayName(displayName, null);
        }
if(mUser.getPhone_number().equals(phoneNumber)){
            //update phoneNumber
            mFirebaseMethods.updatePhoneNumber(null, phoneNumber);
        }
```